# Delete and archive old data from several related tables

Tags: mysql, archive

Our schema looks like this:

- table `tblTrip`: stores start and end trip date and time
- table `tblTripData`: keeps all the trip data
- table `tblTripEvent`: stores events related to the particular trip.

Then we have two more tables, `tblTripEmail` and `tblTripSms`, which store the email and SMS that have been sent according to the events.

We want to keep just 3 months old trip data, we would like, to from time to time, to delete and archive the rest to be stored in offline database.

What is the best mechanism to store in an offline database? I am not sure how partitioning would be helpful because the tables are linked to each other here.

Below is the table desc for tblTripData

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblTripData` (
  `tripDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tripID` int(5) NOT NULL,  
  `deviceSerialNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `speed` float NOT NULL,
  `course` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `gpsdateTimer` datetime NOT NULL, 
  `insertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `odoMeter` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `driverID` int(5) NOT NULL, 
  `eventAlertID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tripDataInsertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL  
  PRIMARY KEY (`tripDataID`),
  KEY `dateTime` (`gpsdateTimer`),
  KEY `tripID` (`tripID`),  
  KEY `eventAlertID` (`eventAlertID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **pt-archiver** from Percona Toolkit, it permits to transfer data on the fly between two MySQL instances.

You can for instance use the `--where` option to filter result set by date.

It's particularly well designed for your needs, because you can transfer data and delete it from source in the same command.

Official page is here : [pt-archiver](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-archiver.html)

An example :

```
pt-archiver --source h=<server_source>,D=<database_source>,t=<your_table> --dest h=<server_target> --where "date_field < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)" --limit 1000 --txn-size 1000 --statistics
```

Add the option `--dry-run` if you want to test.

Add the option `--no-delete` if you want to keep data on source DB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6966/discussion-between-mfouilleul-and-newbie14)